# Entity Framework with MySQL - Timeout Expired while Generating Model

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, edmgen

I've constructed a database in MySQL and I am attempting to map it out with Entity Framework, but I start running into "GenerateSSDLException"s whenever I try to add more than about 20 tables to the EF context.

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.VisualStudio.ModelWizard.Engine.ModelBuilderEngine+GenerateSSDLException'
>   occurred while attempting to update
>   from the database. The exception
>   message is: 'An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See
>   the inner exception for details.'
>
> Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>
> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

There's nothing special about the affected tables, and it's never the same table(s), it's just that after a certain (unspecific) number of tables have been added, the context can no longer be updated without the "Timeout expired" error. Sometimes it's only one table left over, and sometimes it's three; results are pretty unpredictable. Furthermore, the variance in the number of tables which can be added before the error indicates to me that perhaps the problem lies in the size of the query being generated to update the context which includes both the existing table definitions, and also the new tables that are being added to it. Essentially, the SQL query is getting too large and it's failing to execute for some reason.

If I generate the model with [EdmGen2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2) it works without any errors, but the generated EDMX file cannot be updated within Visual Studio without producing the aforementioned exception.

In all likelihood the source of this problem lies in the tool within Visual Studio given that EdmGen2 works fine, but I'm hoping that perhaps others could offer some advice on how to approach this very unique issue, because it seems like [I'm not the only person experiencing it](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,285936,285936).

One suggestion a colleague offered was maintaining two separate EBMX files with some table crossover, but that seems like a pretty ugly fix in my opinion. I suppose this is what I get for trying to use "new technology". :(

Comment: I'm hesitant to upvote any of these answers because none of them really target the actual question... Lizard's response is the only one that resembles an answer, but still not quite there...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help any more, but that is what I would do :p. Would love the upvote if you feel generous! lol

Comment: Nathan: See my answer below. The accepted answer isn't correct for this question.

Comment: @ArenCambre I haven't dealt with this problem for a very long time, and having just reread your response below, I stand by the comment I originally made on that answer. At the time, the problem was in the Entity Framework tool itself and thus could not be helped by me changing code. I'm not saying your solution is incorrect for another, possibly similar, problem, but it was a different issue. Ultimately, the accepted answer on this thread fixed the problem *I* was having.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had headache on this problem in the whole afternoon. However, I found the solution that you can just add a statement in app.config or web.config where your EF desinger connection exists as 'Default Command Timeout=300000;'. The problem's gone.

Comment: What would be the new connection string? I am trying but I am getting this error in output The 'default command timeout' keyword is not supported.

Comment: That is SO annoying...  Nice one!

Comment: You just made my life soooo much easier. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 5):

The above advice is not correct.

`Default Command Timeout` is the only connection string parameter you need to change. `Connect Time` just regulates the amount of time to wait to get a connection in the first place; that is not your problem.

`Default Command Timeout` appears to have no effect in the connection string with Connector/Net 6.3.4. I think this is a bug in Connector/Net, and I filed a [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56806) with Oracle. **EDIT: This bug was acknowledged by MySql developers and has been fixed as of 10/13/2010. Fixes were put in 6.0.8, 6.1.6, 6.2.5, and 6.3.5.**

The only way I got around this was to change my `ObjectContext` object's `CommandTimeout` property to something other than null. If it's null, it's supposed to use the value in the "underlying provider" per MSDN. If not null, it is the authoritative value for number of seconds before a timeout.

For example:

```
var context = new CitationData.de_rawEntities();
context.CommandTimeout = 180;
```

Comment: Specifying CommandTimeout has worked for me in all scenarios; I am however using an older build of .NET Connector and therefore I can not speak in regards to the most recent version. Setting the context.CommandTimeout is not relevant to the problem above because the issue occurs not in code, but rather when selecting "Update Model from Database" in the Entity Framework visual editor/designer.

Comment: Yeah, I only recommended context.CommandTimeout because the Default Command Timeout in the connection string appears to be broken with Connector/Net 6.3.4. Maybe it still works on the version you're on? BTW, CommandTimeout (without space or "Default") appears to be a property of ObjectContext, whereas Default Command Timeout appears to be the connection string property.

Comment: The non-working Default Command Timeout in the connection string was indeed a bug with Connector/Net. This affected all versions since 6.0. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56806 for details (you may have to sign in to see the bug report). As of Oct. 13, versions 6.0.8, 6.1.6, 6.2.5, and 6.3.5 had the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/

Oops, just realised that this link was already posted! sorry

I would also strongly consider "One suggestion a colleague offered was maintaining two separate EBMX files with some table crossover"

It may be ugly, but it should work!

Answer (score 1):

You guys are weak not explaining how to fix the problem easily:

1. Delete all your Data Connections
2. Download the latest MySql Connector (6.3.x)
3. Open Visual Studio >Sever Explorer>Right Click "Data Connections" >Add Connection
4. Choose MySQL Database provider
5. Enter connection details
6. Click on "Advance"
7. Find Connect Time out and make it something like 30,000
8. Find Default Command Timeout and make it something like 30,000

Save everything and then try and update your EF model again. I tested this with EF 4.0 and Vs2010 so I know it works.

Comment: lol!  @Omar, if you are trying to offer a better answer, perhaps you could suggest why this is happening??

Comment: @Omar: You know it works because you tested in on a different version of EF and VS?

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above solution to no avail.  I downloaded the latest .NET connector for MySQL (6.3.6) and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dotConnect for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) with [Entity Developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/). 
 
We have made some improvements in the model generation process in our tools. You can add the Devart Entity Model to your project, which is similar to the ADO.NET Entity Framework model, but has some improvements and does not have the timeout problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities spring to mind:

First is that it is EF version 1 (which shipped with .NET 3.5 SP 1).  See [this](http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework).

The other is that this feels roughly like the same symptoms one got with SQL Server and pre-ODBC drivers (circa 1991) where the wrong type of call was used:  one kind is used with queries returning results (`select`), and the other for statements—not returning a result (`create table`).  Eventually the connection became hopelessly unsynchronized trying to match up SELECT results to the corresponding query.  (In those days, the *Blue Screen Of Death* didn't exist:  the computer tended to reboot voluntarily instead.)

I wonder if the tool is confusing the connection mode in the variety of operations being performed:  creating tables, verifying the created structure, adding a new column, populating rows, and verifying or validating the row content after being filled.  If this is the cause, then it might be averted by being "purer" about the sequence of operations:  do nothing but complete table creates one after another—that is, do nothing which would cause it to create a table then `alter table` to add new columns.

Comment: Not sure how I could do this with the EF tool in Visual Studio. As I explained above if I try to add all of the tables in one operation it fails 100% of the time.