# How to set Entity framework 4 CommandTimeout in connection string?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, connection, app-config

Is it possible to specify commandTimeout in connection string in app.config?

According to this SO question: [Entity Framework with MySQL - Timeout Expired while Generating Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718739/entity-framework-with-mysql-timeout-expired-while-generating-model) the following should work:

```
  <add name="DataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXXX;initial catalog=XXXXX2;persist security info=True;user id=XXXXX;password=XXXXX;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework;Default Command Timeout=12;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

However, it does not work - exception is thrown saying that `Default Command Timeout` is not known part of connection string.

If I do this directly in code using the following code, it works fine:

```
        var db = new DataEntities(); // ObjectContext
        db.CommandTimeout = 1;
```

Does anybody know how to set the commandTimeout using connectionstring or other native option in config?

Thank you.

Comment: It may be worth adding the MySQL tag to the question as this appears to be a feature specific to MySQL?

Comment: No, the underlying DB is MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Ah, that makes things a lot clearer. The link in your post is MySQL specific.

Comment: Thanks @qujck. I missed that somehow (even if it is directly in the title!). So I guess there is no way for SQL server, which is a shame. Please adjust your answer, so I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to set the command timeout in the connection string.

The Command is different object to the connection. A Command can have a connection but it has its own timeout that you can set.

Your example link above is MySQL specific ...

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunatelly it is neither of `Command` or `Connect Timeout`. Still the same exception. You probably meant `Connection Timeout=60;`. However, that deasl with connection timeout not with how long the query should wait to be finished (which is what CommandTimeout is supposed to do).